# Checking with regex right format of a date on BigQuery

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, timestamp

I have to find for a column of a table if there are some date bad formatted, so I wrote this query:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM db_logs.FACT_LOG_WEBSITE
WHERE NOT REGEXP_CONTAINS(CAST(logged_in_at AS STRING), r'^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\.\d{6} UTC$')
```

This query still return date like "2021-07-27 22:11:53.666330 UTC" that respect the regex even if I'm using `NOT`.

I also check on the regex validator to understand if it's a problem of regex but it's working good.

Comment: What's the type of the column? String or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see your confusion - you have some timestamps and looking at it you are creating the regex, but this will explain you what really happens and what will work for you.

```
SELECT logged_in_at as logged_in_at_as_timestamp, cast(logged_in_at as string) logged_in_at_as_string, length(cast(logged_in_at as string)) as length_of_date_string, 
REGEXP_CONTAINS(CAST(logged_in_at AS STRING), r'^\d{4}\-\d{2}\-\d{2} \d{2}\:\d{2}\:\d{2}\.\d{6} UTC$') as existing_regex, 
REGEXP_CONTAINS(CAST(logged_in_at AS STRING), r'^\d{4}\-\d{2}\-\d{2} \d{2}\:\d{2}\:\d{2}\.\d{6}') as new_regex,
safe_cast(logged_in_at as DATE) as parsed_logged_in_at_date,
safe_cast(bad_logged_in_at as DATE) as parsed_bad_logged_in_at_date
 FROM (select current_timestamp() as logged_in_at, current_timestamp()||"00" as bad_logged_in_at)
```

[image]

You can check either safe_cast validation to make sure your timestamp string is real date or not Or you can change your regex, or you can do some other thing. But if you see the first 2 columns you will see why your regex was failing.