# How to convert any type of date format and datetime format into a particular date format using Big Query?

Tags: datetime, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, datetime-format, formatdatetime

I have a Date column with different date format and datetime format. Now, I want to convert the format into `dd-mm-yyyy`. I used `TIMESTAMP_DIFF,PARSE_TIMESTAMP,FORMAT_TIMESTAMP and FORMAT_DATE`. Though it able to convert all but throws error at date time format like `dd/mm/yy HH:MM`. How do I query in Big query so the update statements can convert any kind of dateformat and datetime format ?

```
    data:-
0           21/12/2006
1           25/01/2007
2           20/02/2023
3           1996.12.25
4           24/12/2020
5           24/12/2020
6     24/05/2020 12:02
7     24/05/2020 12:02
8     24/05/2020 12:02
9     24/05/2020 12:02
10          20/02/2023
11          21/02/2023
12          22/02/2023
13          23/02/2023
14          24/02/2023
15          25/02/2023
16          26/02/2023
17          02/12/2020
18          02/23/2020
19          09/23/2020
Name: Date, dtype: object
Big query:-
UPDATE table_name
SET
   Date = CASE
    WHEN TIMESTAMP_DIFF(PARSE_TIMESTAMP('%d/%m/%Y', Date), TIMESTAMP_TRUNC(PARSE_TIMESTAMP('%d/%m/%Y', Date), DAY), SECOND) > 0 THEN
      FORMAT_TIMESTAMP('%d%m%y', PARSE_TIMESTAMP('%d/%m/%Y', Date))
    ELSE
      FORMAT_DATE('%d%m%y', PARSE_DATE('%d/%m/%Y', Date))
  END
WHERE TRUE;

Error:
Failed to parse input string "24/05/2020 12:02"
```

Comment: Hi @data en,I have posted an answer. I hope it will help you. Do consider upvoting and accepting if it helps, otherwise let me know so that I can improve my answer. Please let me know if you would like a full query (update query + case query).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you are encountering is because the PARSE_TIMESTAMP was unable to recognize the format of the input. To solve this error you can consider using "[regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76704869/)" or “[SAFE](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-reference#safe_prefix)” keywords inside the case query. The “SAFE” keyword returns NULL when it sees the bad data or data which is not in the expected format for conversion.

**Example:**

```
select
CASE
    WHEN SAFE.PARSE_TIMESTAMP('%d/%m/%Y', Dates) IS NOT NULL THEN
      FORMAT_TIMESTAMP('%d/%m/%Y', SAFE.PARSE_TIMESTAMP('%d/%m/%Y', Dates))
    WHEN SAFE.PARSE_TIMESTAMP('%Y.%m.%d', Dates) IS NOT NULL THEN
      FORMAT_TIMESTAMP('%d/%m/%Y', SAFE.PARSE_TIMESTAMP('%Y.%m.%d', Dates))
    WHEN SAFE.PARSE_TIMESTAMP('%d/%m/%Y %H:%M', Dates) IS NOT NULL THEN
      FORMAT_TIMESTAMP('%d/%m/%Y', SAFE.PARSE_TIMESTAMP('%d/%m/%Y %H:%M', Dates))
    ELSE   ---Add more when statement to match more date value
      NULL  
  END from t1;
```

**RESULT:**

[image]

For more information you can refer to these [link1](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/timestamp_functions#parse_timestamp) and [link2](https://medium.com/@hakhandare/be-safe-while-querying-bigquery-2f0192f21f3b).